# how to choose diode for PWM of high amperage solenoid?

Tags: mosfet, zener, solenoid, flyback, high-current

I'm making a pulseable solenoid circuit via PWM at around 20 hz.
THe solenoid is a heavy industrial type that pulls a whopping 18 amps.
My snubber circuit gets hot and burns up as the current is too high for the zener and the schottky.

What can I change to allow this circuit to manage the high current fly-back from this solenoid?

[image]

Comment: What is your L estimate considering solenoid DCR  ~ 600 mΩ  and also speed response T of a step change.

Comment: I have no estimate on the coil specification, I only know it works at 14V and pulls 18 amps. I also know i want fast response.

Answer (score 0):

Change the diode to something that's rated for more than 18 amps.

If you need the voltage drop of the zener for a fast turn-off, then replace it with a resistor. Choose the value to give you the voltage you want at 18 amps. Choose the power dissipation to meet the average power that it's being subjected to.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to evaluate how much energy of inductive kickback you have to dissipate since it's also determined by wiring parasitic impedance (but *mainly* by your coil inductance).

Putting bigger components of course is a good solution, as recommended in the comments, as is using an RC snubber (which is somewhat slower, however).

The definitive solution would be active clamping, see https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/6/6307.html for some ideas (of course they want to sell their chip, but the general idea is useful). The appnote also give a formula to estimate the energy to dissipate.